# Why statement ifelse(i == 1,print("yes!"),print("no.")) in R print "no." twice?

Tags: r, if-statement, printing

When i use R in Rstudio Console, i confronted some confusions:

```
i <- 0
ifelse(i == 1,print("yes!"),print("no."))
## [1] "no."
## [1] "no."
```

but when i try non-function, it will print only once:

```
i <- 0
ifelse(i == 1, i + 1, i + 2)
## [1] 2
```

Why Rstudio print twice instead of once in upper situation? What's the difference ?

Comment: because of the print : in the 1st case, it gives you the answer and then prints it, in the 2nd it just gives you the answer

Comment: This is not correct use of `ifelse`. Use `if(i == 1) print("yes!") else print("no.")`.

Comment: @Roland haha~ i am reading "Advanced R" by Hadley Wickham  online <http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html>, he took the same example as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print does two things:

- It prints the parameter
- It returns the parameter

If you just write print("a") on the console, the return value is not shown.

But if you write

```
a = print("a")
a
```

You see both values.

Comment: Wow~ so quick! thank you very much, maybe i need more details knowledge about r.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `print("hello")` (say) not only prints `hello` on the output stream but also returns `hello`. I hope it was helpful.

Comment: your answer is familiar with @fafi 's, thank you too :D

Comment: what about if function? `if`(i == 1,print("yes!"),print("no."))`  from "Advanced R" by Hadley Wickham online <adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html>

Comment: may `if` have variable assignment behind ?

Comment: @Eli `if`'s return value is `invisible`, i.e., not printed when it is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with this in RStudio:

```
i <- 0
a <- 'yes'
b <- 'no'
ifelse(i == 1, a, b)
[1] "no"

ifelse(i == 1, 'yes', 'no')
[1] "no"
```

Either explicitly defining a variable containing the values to return, or indicating the specific value (string, integer, float) within the `ifelse` returns the specific value.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using standard if() {} else {} syntax, you can also fix the problem by using paste() instead of print() within ifelse()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).